# How do I make a usercontrol sizable on runtime? (With sizing handles)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, user-controls, resize

I'm building a usercontrol that's put as a childcomponent in another usercontrol, a parent control. I want the usercontrol to be resizable on runtime, with sizing handles. Basically something like this: (Rotation handle is optional.) 
 [image]

Is there something written in the .net framework to handle this, or do I have to wrte it myself? I'm perfectly willing to write it myself, but because of efficiency I'd like to know if there's something I can use.
I'm using VB.net

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some links that might help:

- [Resize Controls at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20716/Allow-the-User-to-Resize-Controls-at-Runtime)
- [A resizable graphic rectangle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30434/A-Resizable-Graphical-Rectangle)